# Django: Filtering items in generic.ListView

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm creating a game website and i have these models for games:

```py
class Game(models.Model):
    accountant = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='games')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    bank_money = models.IntegerField()
    player_starting_money = models.IntegerField()
    golden_card_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(100),
            MaxValueValidator(1000)
        ]
    )
```

now i want every user to see their own games at dashbard:

```py
class DashboardView(mixins.LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'games/dashboard.html'
    model = models.Game
```

how can i do this (show every user their own games, not all games)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [`get_queryset` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) for your `DashboardView` class to filter out only logged in user games.

```
class DashboardView(mixins.LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'games/dashboard.html'
    model = models.Game

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(accountant=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```